# Gameover on any collision - Swift Spritekit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

In my game I have planes moving around. In my game, I want so that if any plane collides with another, it prints "game over". I have added `SKPhysicsContactDelegate` to my gamescene. I added a physics bodies to my planes. Then, I added this function to my didMoveToView function:

```
  func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact){
        print("Game over")
        }
```

Now, when I run my game, and the planes collide, nothing prints to the console. How can I change my code so if any plane collides with another (there are more than 2) it prints game over to the console?

Edit: I have set the physics world contact delegate to self. I have not called this function - do I have to - I thought that this function runs when there is a collision in the scene.

Here is my code:

```
//
//  GameScene.swift
//  PlaneGame
//
//  Created by Lucas Farleigh on 09/04/2017.
//  Copyright © 2017 Farleigh Tech. All rights reserved.
//

import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

private let Background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Background")
private let PlaneRed = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "PlaneRed")
private let PlaneBlue = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "PlaneBlue")
private let PlaneRed2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "PlaneRed2")
private let PlaneBlue2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "PlaneBlue2")
private let StartButton = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Chalkduster")
private let Trail = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "BlueTrail")
private let Center = SKNode()
private let Center2 = SKNode()
var GameHasStarted = false




override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    //Defining the position,size and ZPosition for the background
    Background.position = CGPoint(x:self.frame.midX / 2,y: self.frame.midY)
    Background.xScale = 10.0
    Background.yScale = 10.0
    Background.zPosition = -10
    addChild(Background)



    //Defining a start button - will be used later as a button
    StartButton.position = CGPoint(x:self.frame.midX,y:self.frame.minY + 100)
    StartButton.text = "Tap Anywhere To Start"
    StartButton.fontSize = 50.0
    StartButton.name = "StartButton"
    addChild(StartButton)

    //Setting the planered position and size up for the plane, ready to start the game
    PlaneRed.position = CGPoint(x:self.frame.midX - 250,y: self.frame.midY)
    PlaneRed.xScale = 0.13
    PlaneRed.yScale = 0.13
    PlaneRed.zPosition = 10
    //Setting the planeblue position and size up for the plane, ready to start the game
    PlaneBlue.position = CGPoint(x:self.frame.midX + 250,y: self.frame.midY)
    PlaneBlue.xScale = 0.13
    PlaneBlue.yScale = -0.13
    PlaneBlue.zPosition = 10

    //Setting the planered position and size up for the plane, ready to start the game
    PlaneRed2.position = CGPoint(x:self.frame.midX,y: self.frame.midY + 250)
    PlaneRed2.xScale = -0.13
    PlaneRed2.yScale = 0.13
    PlaneRed2.zPosition = 10
    //Setting the planeblue position and size up for the plane, ready to start the game
    PlaneBlue2.position = CGPoint(x:self.frame.midX,y: self.frame.midY - 250)
    PlaneBlue2.xScale = 0.13
    PlaneBlue2.yScale = 0.13
    PlaneBlue2.zPosition = 10


    //Making the trail
    Trail.position = CGPoint(x:self.frame.midX,y:self.frame.midY)
    Trail.xScale = 1.08
    Trail.yScale = 1.08
    addChild(Trail)

    //In order to rotate the planes around a point, we must create the point as an SKNode, and make the planes a child of the point
    //The point then rotates bringing the planes with it
    //Setting up the point where the plane will rotate around
    Center.position = CGPoint(x:self.frame.midX,y:self.frame.midY)
    addChild(Center)
    Center2.position = CGPoint(x:self.frame.midX,y:self.frame.midY)
    addChild(Center2)
    Center.addChild(PlaneRed)
    Center.addChild(PlaneBlue)
    Center2.addChild(PlaneRed2)
    Center2.addChild(PlaneBlue2)



    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //ADDING PHYSICS TO PLANES
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Defining the red planes physics body
    PlaneRed.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: PlaneRed.size)
    PlaneRed2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: PlaneRed2.size)
    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector.zero
    func didBegin(contact: SKPhysicsContact){
        print("Game over")

    }
}








func Start(){
    //Defining an SKAction for the plane to orbit the center
    let OrbitCenter = SKAction.rotate(byAngle: CGFloat(-2), duration: 3.8)
    let Orbit = SKAction.repeatForever(OrbitCenter)
    //Creating the action for the center 2 to rotate anti clockwise
    let AntiOrbitCenter = SKAction.rotate(byAngle: CGFloat(2), duration: 3.8)
    let AntiOrbit = SKAction.repeatForever(AntiOrbitCenter)

    //Running the SKAction on the plane
    Center.run(Orbit)
    Center2.run(AntiOrbit)


}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?){
    for touch in touches{
    //Setting up the touch settings - these two variables store the nodes that the user has touched by first defining the location and then checking for nodes at this location
    let location = touch.location(in: self)
    let node = self.atPoint(location)


        if GameHasStarted == false{
            Start()
            GameHasStarted = true

        }





    }
}




override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    // Called before each frame is rendered
} 
}
```

Comment: Are you executing this function somewhere in your code?

Comment: @maximilian_cs As he said, it is executed by the delegate.

Comment: Have you set the `SKPhysicsContactDelegate` to `self`?

Comment: Yes, I have - forgot to add will do now. I have not executed this function in my code.

Comment: @LucasFarleighCan you add the code of where you add the PhysicsBodies to the planes?

Comment: Sure will do now

Comment: Why is your `didBegin(contact)` inside your `didMove(to view)`?

Comment: there are some good, simple examples of how to implement collisions and contact in the sprite-kit documentation here on SO - http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sprite-kit/6261/sknode-collision#t=201704240830256969282

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First

> Your didBegin func needs to be outside of didMove func

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
}

func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    print("Game over")
}
```

second

> you need to setup some physics categories for your objects so they
>   know what they can collide with, what they can pass through and what
>   collisions don't matter. You can put this outside your class
>   declaration

```
//Game Physics
struct PhysicsCategory {
    static let plane: UInt32 = 0x1 << 0
    static let plane2: UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
    static let obstacle: UInt32 = 0x1 << 2
}
```

third

> You need to add those physics decorations to your objects

```
    //Defining the red planes physics body
    PlaneRed.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: PlaneRed.size)
    PlaneRed.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.plane
    PlaneRed.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.plane
    PlaneRed.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.plane
    PlaneRed.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true

    PlaneRed2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: PlaneRed2.size)
    PlaneRed2.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.plane
    PlaneRed2.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.plane
    PlaneRed2.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.plane
    PlaneRed2.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true

    PlaneBlue.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: PlaneBlue.size)
    PlaneBlue.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.plane
    PlaneBlue.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.plane
    PlaneBlue.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.plane
    PlaneBlue.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true

    PlaneBlue2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: PlaneBlue2.size)
    PlaneBlue2.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.plane
    PlaneBlue2.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.plane
    PlaneBlue2.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.plane
    PlaneBlue2.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true

    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector.zero
```

Comment: How come all the physics categories are set to the same value(0 x 1)

Comment: They look the same but they're not. They're bitmasks You can also set them to powers of 2 plane = 0, plane2 = 1 obstacle = 2, ground = 4. more can be read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24069703/how-to-define-category-bit-mask-enumeration-for-spritekit-in-swift

Comment: Why do we need to use UInt32 for categories? Also - I have seen the word bitmask many times in different places. I know a very very basic definition 
 however, I have seen it in many places, for example, categoryBitMask - what would be a basic definition universally?

Comment: Lucas, I'm not an expert on bitmasks. I barely understand them myself. If you have a day to invest I suggest you read up on them, but it's not an easy subject

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, however, why do I need to add static when defining the categories, because when I do not I get an error.

Comment: Sorry @LucasFarleigh i'm at work and can't really get into this. My best suggestion would be to post these as a new question regarding physicsBody categories. As it really is part of this question