# PhysicsBody is nil using SpriteKit with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have a SpriteKit game I am building and I am loading a level from a multidimensional array. The loadlevel function works the first time.  It does fail if I do a `println` of the `physicsBody` above the `physicsBody` assignment (after the initialization of the physicBody). When I remove all the tiles with `removeChildrenInArray` the secondtime I run load level it throws an error saying `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional` and it points to line right below the `println` below. And the `println` indicates that it is the `physicsBody` that is `nil`. In my mind there is no reason a freshly initialize `PhysicsBody` should ever be `nil`. The `println` prints `physicsBody nil`. I have no idea why the `physicsBody` would be `nil`.  I am just trying to reset the level by removing all block nodes and adding new ones in the original place according to the level map.

```
func loadLevel() {
    var levels = Levels().data
    var frameSize = view.frame.size
    var thisLevel = levels[currentLevel]
    println("running load level")
    for (rowIndex,row) in enumerate(thisLevel) {
        for (colIndex,col) in enumerate(row) {
            if col == 4 {
                continue
            }
            println("COL: \(col)")
            var tile = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "brick_\(tileMap[col])"))
            tile.name = "tile_\(rowIndex)_\(colIndex)"
            tile.position.y = frameSize.height - (tile.size.height * CGFloat(rowIndex)) - (tile.size.height/2)
            tile.position.x = tile.size.width  * CGFloat(colIndex) + (tile.size.width/2)
            var physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: tile.size)
            tile.physicsBody = physicsBody
            tile.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = false
            tile.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Block.toRaw()
            tile.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Ball.toRaw()
            tile.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Ball.toRaw()
            scene.addChild(tile)
            tileCount++
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my ColliderType

```
enum ColliderType:UInt32 {
    case Paddle = 1
    case Block = 2
    case Wall = 3
    case Ball = 4
}
```

This is my reset function contents:

```
func reset() {
    tileCount = 0
    var removeTiles = [SKSpriteNode]()
    // remove all the tiles
    for child in scene.children {
        var a_tile = child as SKSpriteNode
        if a_tile.name.hasPrefix("tile_") {
            a_tile.removeFromParent()
            a_tile.name = ""
            removeTiles.append(a_tile)
        }
    }
    removeTiles.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    ball!.position = CGPoint(x: 200, y: 200)
    ballVel = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -5)
    currentLevel++
    loadLevel()
    lost = false
    won = false
}
```

Here is my `Level` structs

```
struct Tile {
    let map = ["blue","green","purple","red"]
}

struct Levels {
    let data = [
        [
            [4,4,0,4,0,4,0,4,0,4,0,4,0,0,4,4],
            [4,4,1,4,1,4,1,4,1,4,1,4,1,1,4,4],
            [4,4,2,4,2,4,2,4,2,4,2,4,2,2,4,4],
            [4,4,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,3,4,4]
        ],
        [
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
            [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,4,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
            [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]
        ]
    ]
}
```

If this is a bug in Swift I am trying to figure out a way around so I can just make this work.

Comment: any reason why you assign the body to a var first rather than directly to tile.physicsBody?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Just trying things out from this error. I was doing as you say the first couple of times.

Comment: Well actually, for starters, you should not be using the built in physics engine in swift for a platformer. It is too intensive to make a physics body for each tile and can cause glitches. Read more here: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2013/08/physics-engine-platformer-terrible-idea/h Second of all, your remove function can be simplied to scene.removeAllChildren()

Comment: I tried your code and I can't reproduce the problem. Can you reduce it to a smaller example that still has the problem? By the way, using `enum` like that is wrong since `Wall == Block & Paddle` it will collide with both. You might want to use [`RawOptionSet`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24066170/swift-ns-options-style-bitmask-enumerations).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `SKPhysicsBody` is instantiated with an empty size. Try to create the physics body object with an explicit size, like so:

```
var physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(100, 100))
```

Alternatively, you can set the size directly on the `SKSpriteNode` or use one of its constructors that take a CGSize construct like `initWithTexture:color:size:`