# 'YearCalendarUnit' was deprecated in OS X version 10.10: Use NSCalendarUnitYear instead

Tags: ios, macos, swift

My code:

```
 let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
 let dateComponents = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.YearCalendarUnit | NSCalendarUnit.MonthCalendarUnit | NSCalendarUnit.DayCalendarUnit, fromDate: self)
```

My error:

```
'YearCalendarUnit' was deprecated in OS X version 10.10: Use NSCalendarUnitYear instead
'MonthCalendarUnit' was deprecated in OS X version 10.10: Use NSCalendarUnitMonth instead
'DayCalendarUnit' was deprecated in OS X version 10.10: Use NSCalendarUnitDay instead
```

But I can't type 
NSCalendarUnitYear as well as (NSCalendarUnitMonth/ NSCalendarUnitDay)
What is wrong?

Comment: Why you can't type this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `let dateComponents = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitYear | .CalendarUnitMonth | .CalendarUnitDay, fromDate: self)`

Edit:

This is because the error messages are for Objective-C, not adapted for swift.

Edit 2: see Will's comment for Swift 2 and on.

Comment: .CalendarUnitYear is also valid in the context of an NSCalendarUnit

Comment: As of Swift 2, you use the `OptionSetType` syntax. For this same code, it'd look like `calendar.components([.Year, .Month, .Day] , fromDate: self)` See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24066170/how-to-create-ns-options-style-bitmask-enumerations-in-swift for more