# Swift Type Inference mixup?

Tags: swift2, type-inference, xcode7-beta6

This assigns an array of UIUserNotificationType to a variable of UIUserNotificationType. This should not work:

1)

```
var userNotificationTypes: UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.Alert, UIUserNotificationType.Badge, UIUserNotificationType.Sound]
print(userNotificationTypes.dynamicType) // UIUserNotificationType
```

Here is the type of [UIUserNotificationType]

2)

```
let intermidiate = [UIUserNotificationType.Alert, UIUserNotificationType.Badge, UIUserNotificationType.Sound]
print(intermidiate.dynamicType) // Array<UIUserNotificationType>
```

Attempting to assign it fails as expected:

3)

```
userNotificationTypes = intermidiate // Cannot assign a value of type '[UIUserNotificationType]' to a value of type 'UIUserNotificationType'
```

Attempting to assign `[UIUserNotificationType]` to `UIUserNotificationType` obviously does not work, so why does `1)` compiles ?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for `[.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]` can be used for 2 different purposes. It can define an `Array<UIUserNotificationType>` or create bit mask populated `OptionTypeSet` for `UIUserNotificationType`

The result is dependent on the declared type of assignment variable.

#### OptionSetType

`let userNotificationTypes: UIUserNotificationType = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]`

`userNotificationTypes` is actually an OptionSetType bit mask, which is from C's point of view looks like `(UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound)`

#### Array

`let userNotificationTypes: [UIUserNotificationType] = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]`

`userNotificationTypes` is Array of `UIUserNotificationType` types.

Comment: Same syntax produces 2 different results based on the assignment type. That's a bit confusing IMHO. More info here http://stackoverflow.com/a/31099051/48062

Comment: The bracket syntax `[..., ..., ..., ...]` for initializing a type is called an `ArrayLiteral` and you can conform to the protocol `ArrayLiteralConvertible` to initialize your own type with an `ArrayLiteral`. `Arrays`, `Sets` and types which conform to `OptionSetType` are by default `ArrayLiteralConvertible`.