# How to create a custom UIControlEvent in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, custom-controls, user-interaction, uicontrolevents

I'm creating a custom UI-Element and want to trigger a custom UIControlEvent. I already found out, that there is a range ApplicationReserved.

Sadly this doesn't work, because it "does not conform to protocol 'RawRepresentable':

```
enum MyCustomEvents : UIControlEvents{
  case Increase = 0x01000000
  case Decrease = 0x02000000
}
```

Two questions:
1) Is this the right approach for custom events?
2) How can I define custom events correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since UIControlEvents are created as a struct of OptionSetType in Swift 2.0, you can create custom UIControlEvents in the same way.

For your question, it will be

```
struct MyCustomEvents : OptionSetType{
    let rawValue : UInt

    static let Increase = MyCustomEvents(rawValue: 0x01000000)
    static let Decrease = MyCustomEvents(rawValue: 0x02000000)
}
```

For adding a target/action to this custom UIControlEvent, you need to cast this as a UIControl Event.

```
let controlEvent : UIControlEvents = UIControlEvents.init(rawValue: MyCustomEvents.Increase.rawValue)
sliderControl.addTarget(self, action: "increaseAction:", forControlEvents: controlEvent)
```

Comment: For details on NS_Options style bitmask enumerations, checkout this answer : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24066170/how-to-create-ns-options-style-bitmask-enumerations-in-swift

Comment: @user3726405 : Please accept the answer if it helped you, or let me know in case you are facing any issues

Comment: this works! Extending from OptionsSetType made the difference. Thanks

Comment: Can you write please how can you trigger this custom "Increase" action from inside a custom class?

Comment: @UditS, how do you know which the `rawValue` values are fine for use? Might the `0x01000000` already stand for some event?

Comment: ahh, found the docs.. so answering my own question: `UIControlEventApplicationReserved = 0x0F000000,`

Comment: so that appears to be, egh 15 events

Answer (score 15):

Since what you want is just another `UIControlEvent`, you can use (as you were before) the range defined by `.applicationReserved` as a free space for you to use. Though, a more correct and easy to use way to do this would be:

(Swift 3.0):

```
extension UIControlEvents {
    static var increased: UIControlEvents { return UIControlEvents(rawValue: 0b0001 << 24) }
    static var decreased: UIControlEvents { return UIControlEvents(rawValue: 0b0010 << 24) }
}
```

In this way you can easily use this definitions everywhere events are supposed to be used, also with the convenience of type inference (e.g. `sendActions(for: [.valueChanged, .increased])`).

The declaration also looks cleaner to me as being these bits it's easier to see that they're disjoint by using a shift. Since `.applicationReserved` is defined as `0b1111 << 24`, it's more definite which parts of it you're using.

These can be `public` if needed, and there's not much difference between having computed `var`s like here or just assigning `let` constants.

Comment: Is there way to set these control events available in interface builder?

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5**

the UIControlEvents has been renamed to UIControl.Event

```
extension UIControl.Event {

    static var dismissed: UIControl.Event = UIControl.Event(rawValue: 0b0010 << 24)
}
```