# CGGradientDrawingOptions error in Swift?

Tags: swift, label, cgpoint

I am creating a `UILabel` that will have a gradient background color. The only problem is I am getting an error message saying the following:

"Cannot covert value of type `Int` to expected argument type CGGradientDrawingOptions"

I am wondering if this is because of a simple syntax error or if I need to add or delete something from my code. Please inform me on what I need to add, delete, or fix in your answer and what the error means. Here is all the code:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class PHLabel: UILabel {

@IBInspectable var startColor: UIColor = UIColor.greenColor()
@IBInspectable var endColor: UIColor = UIColor.greenColor()

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
let colors = [startColor.CGColor, endColor.CGColor]

let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()

let colorLocations:[CGFloat] = [0.0, 1.0]

let gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, colors, colorLocations)

var startPoint = CGPoint.zero
var endPoint = CGPoint(x:0, y:self.bounds.height)
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, 0)
}
}
```

Any suggestions or input is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first Google hit for "CGContextDrawLinearGradient swift 2" is https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/17470, and there  `CGGradientDrawingOptions(rawValue: 0)` or simply `[]` is suggested as solution for the options argument. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24066170/how-to-create-ns-options-style-bitmask-enumerations-in-swift.

Answer (score 2):

CGGradientDrawingOptions is an OptionSetType and cannot be implicitly cast from an Int (since Swift 2).

```
struct CGGradientDrawingOptions : OptionSetType {
      init(rawValue rawValue: UInt32)
      static var DrawsBeforeStartLocation: CGGradientDrawingOptions { get }
      static var DrawsAfterEndLocation: CGGradientDrawingOptions { get }
}
```

In your case the zero value is [ ]. If you want to use options, you can type something like this :

```
let opts: CGGradientDrawingOptions = [
    .DrawsBeforeStartLocation,
    .DrawsAfterEndLocation
]
CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, opts)
```

As Martin.R. said above you can also use CGGradientDrawingOptions(rawValue: 0) but it is not appropriate in your case.

Comment: Is there a simple fix that I can use in place of the 0?

Comment: You can replace 0 by [].
CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, [])

Comment: It worked, thanks. But just one more question, how do I add text to this label?

Comment: The UILabel has a text attribute. You have to draw this string in the drawRect method. Something as (self.string as? NSString)?.drawInRect ...
You can also use the attributedText attribute instead of the text attribute.

Comment: I made a mistake. It is not (self.string as? NSString) but (self.text as? NSString)

All methods to draw a NSString are listed here : https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/index.html

Answer (score 0):

SWIFT 2.0

Use as below in swift 2. jsut type the dot and select the option. 
 CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint,.DrawsAfterEndLocation)