# How to have no collision between nodes of a kind

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to make a game with a player block and a few obstacle blocks. The player can collide with the obstacle but the obstacles should not collide with each other but instead "pass through" each other. I have the following enumeration for my bit mask:

```
enum bitMask: UInt32 {
    case player = 1
    case obstacle = 2
    case frame = 4
}
```

This is how I define my player block:

```
let player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "yellow-square")
player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: player.texture!, size: player.frame.size)
player.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
player.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = bitMask.player.rawValue
player.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = bitMask.obstacle.rawValue
player.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = 0
addChild(player)
player.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = bitMask.obstacle.rawValue
player.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = bitMask.frame.rawValue
```

my obstacle blocks (in a for loop):

```
let obstacle = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "black-square")
obstacle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: obstacle.texture!, size: obstacle.frame.size)
boundaryNode.addChild(obstacle)
obstacle.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(-15, -10))
obstacle.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = bitMask.obstacle.rawValue
obstacle.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = bitMask.player.rawValue
```

and my contact function:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let contactMask = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask
    switch(contactMask) {
        case bitMask.player.rawValue | bitMask.obstacle.rawValue:
            let yourTimeNode = contact.bodyB.node
            yourTimeNode?.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false

            let firstNode = contact.bodyA.node
            firstNode?.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false

            print("Collision")
        default:
            return
    }
}
```

Currently every block collides with each other and I do not know how to turn off collision between obstacles and keep the collision between the obstacle and player block.

Comment: Unrelated: For your bitmask I believe you are looking for [OptionSetType](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24066170/how-to-create-ns-options-style-bitmask-enumerations-in-swift/24066171#24066171)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a few things in your code to change. First you should make the bit masks like so

```
struct BitMask {
     static let player: UInt32 = 0x1 << 0
     static let obstacle: UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
     static let frame: UInt32 = 0x1 << 2
}
```

this way you only need to increase the last number by 1, which makes your life easier if you start adding a lot more bit masks. Than you call it like so

```
...categoryBitMask = BitMask.obstacle // no need for rawValue
```

Than you should change your contact method to look more like this

```
/// Did Begin Contact
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    var firstBody: SKPhysicsBody
    var secondBody: SKPhysicsBody

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    } else {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }

    if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == BitMask.player) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == BitMask.obstacle) {
        // do your thing 
    }
}
```

And finally in your player and obstacle code, firstly in the player code you are repeating 2 values (contactBitMask/categoryBitMask), so delete them. 
Secondly the reason your obstacle are colliding with each other is because you have not set a collisionBitMask for your obstacles. This makes it default 0xFFFFFFFF which means all bits are set and it will interact with everything. To fix it add this to the obstacle code

```
 obstacle.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = BitMask.player
```

which now makes the obstacles only collide with the player.

Comment: By default, the [collisionBitMask](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsBody/collisionBitMask) has all bits set ( 0xFFFFFFFF ). So, when logical AND operator is performed between obstacle's collision bit mask and other object's category bit mask, the result will be non-zero value. That is why the collisions will occur between obstacles and other bodies even if you don't set collision bit mask on obstacle explicitly.

Comment: I guess that you understand that 0xFFFFFFFF is not equivalent for zero , but rather equal to 4294967295, which is UInt32.max, so you should slightly change your answer.

Comment: I know what you mean and realised my answer is technically wrong there. Its not worth really explaining so I just removed the last part and slightly edited the other. Thanks

Comment: It happens...But still you have the same  error(probably a typo this time). You haven't removed that zero which was the point of my comment. I am talking about this part: " This makes it default to 0 (0xFFFFFFFF)" , it should be : This makes it default to 0xFFFFFFFF (which is 4294967295).

Comment: sorry I am getting confused with my own bitMasks now haha. I made 2.5 games so I should now lmao.

Comment: :) No worries. All other things were correct, and this one is fixed now, so I give you an upvote :)

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it. Been a long day haha

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly although I think you meant - obstacle.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = BitMask.player