# No '|' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'NSTextStorageEditActions'

Tags: ios, swift

I went through the [Text Kit Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/77092/text-kit-tutorial-swift) on [raywenderlich.com](http://raywenderlich.com) and the line

```
edited(.EditedCharacters | .EditedAttributes, range: range, changeInLength: (str as NSString).length - range.length)
```

produces the following error:

```
No '|' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'NSTextStorageEditActions'
```

The error goes away when I change the first argument to:

```
edited(.EditedCharacters, range: range, changeInLength: (str as NSString).length - range.length)
```

I also tried using "OR" and "||" without any success.

Swift 2.2 and iOS 9.2

Comment: [`NSTextStorageEditActions`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextStorage_Class/#//apple_ref/c/econst/NSTextStorageEditedCharacters) is nowadays (seems like the tutorial is pre-Swift 2.0) conforming to `OptionSetType` protocol, and you can include several options using the array-like syntax `[.OptionA, .OptionB]`. E.g., in your example, `edited([.EditedCharacters, .EditedAttributes], ... `. For details, [see e.g. this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24066170/how-to-create-ns-options-style-bitmask-enumerations-in-swift).

Comment: Ahh! That worked - thanks!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

@dfri is correct. To illustrate another example of using the pipe, "|", is when doing the autoResizingMask for UIImageView as follows:

`imageView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight, ...]`

Of course you'd replace the `...` with other `UIViewAutoresizing` options.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Put them all in an array like below:

instead of pipe

```
let timeDateComponents = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.Hour| NSCalendarUnit.Minute| NSCalendarUnit.Second, fromDate: NSDate())
```

try this

```
let timeDateComponents = calendar.components([NSCalendarUnit.Hour, NSCalendarUnit.Minute, NSCalendarUnit.Second], fromDate: NSDate())
```