# Convert Obj-C #define statement into format Swift 2.0 can understand

Tags: objective-c, swift2

The `INT_Command` object declaration below is part of an Objective-C class that is bridged into my Swift 2.0 project. Only my Swift classes do not recognise it, because it needs recoding as an... `enum`? Right?

I am aware there are existing posts on this subject, but `INT_Command` is a *very specific* `#define` statement that I cannot find any guidance on:

```
#define INT_Command(command,integ,data) ((((UInt16)command&INT_CMDMASK)<<INT_CMDOFFSET)|(((UInt16)integ&INT_INTMASK)<<INT_INTOFFSET)|(((UInt16)data&INT_DATAMASK)<<INT_DATAOFFSET))
```

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Just write it as a function. My only question would be that it doesn't feel like it deserves to be a top-level function, but probably belongs within some class that is dealing with these data and command types.

Comment: Can you describe a bit about the values of `command`, `integ`, and `data`? If they're all bitwise options, then rather than a strict port that simply rewrites this macro into a function, you might refactor this into a `OptionSetType` (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24066170/how-to-create-ns-options-style-bitmask-enumerations-in-swift). We need more information about the nature of the three values in order to recommend a Swift design.