# No '|' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'CGGradientDrawingOptions'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift2

Going back through an old project I was going to add some features and ran into this error. Does anyone know how to eliminate this? It happened for the code below:

```
UInt32(CGGradientDrawingOptions.DrawsBeforeStartLocation) | UInt32(CGGradientDrawingOptions.DrawsAfterEndLocation))
```

Below is the full file:

```
import UIKit

class BackgroundView: UIView {

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

        // Background View

        //// Color Declarations
        var lightPurple: UIColor = UIColor(red: 0.377, green: 0.075, blue: 0.778, alpha: 1.000)
        var darkPurple: UIColor = UIColor(red: 0.060, green: 0.036, blue: 0.202, alpha: 1.000)

        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        //// Gradient Declarations
        let purpleGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), [lightPurple.CGColor, darkPurple.CGColor], [0, 1])

        //// Background Drawing
        let backgroundPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.width, self.frame.height))
        CGContextSaveGState(context)
        backgroundPath.addClip()
        CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, purpleGradient,
            CGPointMake(160, 0),
            CGPointMake(160, 568),
            UInt32(CGGradientDrawingOptions.DrawsBeforeStartLocation) | UInt32(CGGradientDrawingOptions.DrawsAfterEndLocation))
        CGContextRestoreGState(context)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CGGradientDrawingOptions` since Swift 2.0 [implements OptionSetType](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGradient/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CGGradientDrawingOptions). This means that `|` operator is no longer necessary and you can write it like this:

```
let options: CGGradientDrawingOptions = [.DrawsBeforeStartLocation, .DrawsAfterEndLocation]
```

To get more info you can [go here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24066170/how-to-create-ns-options-style-bitmask-enumerations-in-swift)

Comment: Great thanks, that worked.

Answer (score -1):

Try to group them in `Array` instead.