# Objective-C NS_OPTIONS in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, bit-fields

I'm given an `NS_OPTIONS` defined in Objective-C:

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSInteger, MyType) {
   MyTypeOption1 = 1 << 0,
   MyTypeOption2 = 1 << 1,
   MyTypeOption3 = 1 << 2,
   // etc
}
```

I'm importing this type into Swift, but I can't form bit fields.

```
let default : MyType = MyTypeOption1 | MyTypeOption2
```

The error:

```
Protocol 'BinaryInteger' requires that 'MyType' conform to 'BinaryInteger'
```

The IDE indicates that it is the standing-colon bitwise-or operator which is the problem.

Altering the `NS_OPTIONS` declarations or declaring a new type with Swift's `OptionSet` aren't ... options. How can I get Swift to play ball?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your syntax is simply wrong. The Swift syntax for a bit field (which is actually called an `OptionSet` in Swift) is the array syntax, not the bitwise OR syntax.

Objective-C enums created using `NS_OPTIONS` are automatically imported into Swift as `OptionSet`s.

So you just need to do `let default: MyType = [.option1, .option2]` instead of trying to replicate the Obj-C bitfield syntax.

For more info on the topic, see [How to create NS_OPTIONS-style bitmask enumerations in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24066170/how-to-create-ns-options-style-bitmask-enumerations-in-swift)